# should I use one component for edit and view with ngif or divided them to components?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular application I have two urls: `localhost:4200/report/11/view` and `localhost:4200/report/11/edit`.

In view page I divide the areas to components like this:
  --> render h2 with title.
  -> render ul-li with list of companies belong to this report.
  -> render p.

In my edit page I make those component editable:
  --> render input with title.
  -> render ul-li with list of companies belong to this report, and autocomplete to add to the list.
  -> render input.

My question is should I use seperate components for view and edit or inside the component I use ngIf to display or not the right part?

Comment: No, you can use a single component so based on the boolean you can enable the field to edit the field or not. Thats the simplest approach

Comment: I would say use a ngIf to be more dry as possible.

I probably will use this strategy:
One shared stateless component who can emit an event in Output on edit and get in Input the list items to display and the parameter to understand if the "edit mode" is true or false.

Comment: I would go to `SOC`!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale can you please give more reference of how to do SOC in angular...

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Added an answer, I thought its important point as these day's have seen this type of development stuff!

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline edit or you can use `<ng-container>` based on *ngIf Like:

In your TS file:

```
edit: boolean = true
// Other code ...
```

In your template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="edit === false">
   <!-- your snippet when edit mode is off. -->
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="edit === true">
   <!-- your snippet when edit mode is on. -->
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not predefined pattern it totally depends on how you want it to extend in future to make the code more reusable.

So yes, you can create a single component to handle both `edit` and `view` screen by maintaining a flag and rendering the required view.

For a more reusable approach. You can follow the design patterns something like creating an `abstract class` for the view and extending them to all your common components. In this way your code will be clean in any scenario, and support extensibility in future.

Answer (score 2):

I would use two separate components for both Edit and View the data:

1. To maintain clean code i.e No need to deal with structural
   directives like `*ngIf` etc to render HTML controls.
2. If you made ***changes*** in one feature then you have to test both
   feature  (which is TDS and Error prone)
3. Better to maintain and easy to understand -- In case if you want to add new text box if a Edit module then no need to add if to render it
4. Separate of Concern - As both functionality is different so keep it
   separate

Comment: For maximum Component Re-Usability, Which type of pattern is helpful in angular. So that two features are different but both sharing same component because of same user-interface interaction. for example `Abstract-Factory-Design-Pattern` where we are adding new class and removing one class without affecting to each-other.. How we can achieve this with component design? Can you provide best practices with one e-commerce use-case... Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you don't use *ngIf if you separate in two components? You need to tell HTML which one to render if there are two components, each one has an app-selector.